# Fetch the data from Mongo Database Collections with Join

Tags: mongodb

I am very new to Mongo Database, can someone help me to find the way to get the details based on my two collection structure

I have two collections collection1 and collectiond2 and I wanted to get only objects from collection2 which have a reference in collection1

Can you please help me with the approach

**collection1**

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5bb899b1d2c457823df1dxyz"
    },
    "top_element": {
        "_ref": {
            "$ref": "collection2",
            "$id": "top_element_123"
        }
    },
    "bottom_element": {
        "_ref": {
            "$ref": "collection2",
            "$id": "bottom_element_123"
        }
    }
}
```

**collection2**

```
{
    "_id": "top_element_123",
    "parent": "parent1",
    "child": "child1"
},
{
    "_id": "bottom_element_123",
    "parent": "parent1",
    "child": "child2",
},
{
    "_id": "top_element_456",
    "parent": "parent2",
    "child": "child2",
},
{
    "_id": "top_element_456",
    "parent": "parent2",
    "child": "child3",
}
```

**My Expected Output**

```
{
    "_id": "top_element_123",
    "parent": "parent1",
    "child": "child1"
},
{
    "_id": "bottom_element_123",
    "parent": "parent1",
    "child": "child2",
}
```

Comment: Field names may not start with `$`.

Comment: _id field in all collection is must be unique.